# System.Addin get HostView from token without activating

Tags: c#-4.0, maf, system.addin

Is there anyway to obtain the HostView of a token without activating that token? In my program I activate the token when the wpf window loads and then, in a separate class, I need to access the HostView of a specific token.

After some initial checks online I could not find any method that would do this, so my guess is that there is not a 1:1 correlation between a token and a specific HostView (ie one token could have multiple views). Am I way off on this?

Comment: I think you are right since the [QualificationData] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.hosting.addintoken.qualificationdata.aspx) is always empty for the HostViewOfAddIn segment. Anyway, the HostView should be accesses only after activation. Why don't you pass it from one class to the other (dependency injection)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it makes more sense why it can't be done now. I'll give dependency injection a shot.